# Standalone Jupyter install - Pandas, tabnine not found, installed to wrong directory

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pyenv

I have installed Python 3.9.0 using pyenv. I want to avoid anaconda. I have installed jupyter using pip3.  Here are my paths.

```
❯ pyenv --version
pyenv 1.2.21 

❯ pyenv which python
/Users/np/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python


❯ pyenv which jupyter
/Users/np/.pyenv/versions/jupyter3/bin/jupyter
```

I can get Jupyter notebook to launch from the terminal. I want to install Pandas so I used

```
pip3 install pandas
```

and it installed to the directory .pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)

This is obviously a different directory to my python and jupyter. As you may tell I don't really know what I am doing with pyenv.
How can i ensure my pandas (and other installs eg tabnine - similar problem) are installed to the /Users/np/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python directory.

I have run

```
pyenv global 3.9.0
```

and then

```
pyenv rehash
```

then

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

Jupyter is **now** being installed to

```
./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

when

```
pyenv which python
```

shows my global python is in

```
/Users/np/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/python
```

and

```
pyenv which jupyter
```

shows

```
pyenv: jupyter: command not found
```

I have

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

in my ~/.zshrc.
Whats more when I launch jupyter notebook from the terminal the kernel in JN reports

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/np/.pyenv/versions/jupyter3/bin/python'
```

which sounds like an old reference to virtualenv which I have now removed as overcomplicating my needs.

Notebook is installed to

```
.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Why is pyenv not coordinating the installs of these packages to my python directory.

Comment: you should set the global value in pyenv `pyenv global 3.9.0` then `pyenv rehash`. this will make 3.9.0 the main version to use.  Reinstall jupyter and do all the pip3 in there after that. It took me a while to work this out...

Comment: Have edited the original post - still having wrong directory install issues.